# PHP: Getting contents of a file that is newer than a time

Tags: php

Currently I have a PHP scripts that serves a medium amount (200 lines) of text. What I was wondering if it were possible to get the contents of a text file that is newest than a time, perhaps PHP's filemtime() for its last modification.

Is it possible to get the contents of a text file in this manner?

Edit: filemtime() is illogical since it wouldn't have any updates past that time.

To clear it up, I'm trying to get all the inner contents of a text file that is newer than a time.

Example: line1 was posted at time1, line2 was posted at time2, so on. I would want to be able to specify time2 and get the contents of the file that is newer than time2.

Comment: Are you trying to only open a file if it's filemtime() is newer than a specific time? Or load any file whose filemtime() is newer than a specific time?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to timestamp all entries into the file. Then using standard `fopen()`/`fread()` functions, read the contents in line by line. You would then need to filter the time using regular expression matching like `preg_match()` and compare that to the time you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "the contents from a file where the *file* is newer than a certain time", then yes. You seem to have answered your own question.  Use `filemtime()` if you care about the modification time, and compare it to the time you are interested in.

If you mean "the contents from a file where the *contents* are newer than a certain time", then no, not without some other way of identifying which contents in the file are newer than the time you are interested in.  (For example, if each line of the file began with a timestamp indicating when that line was written, you could use that.) This is because filesystems do not typically keep track of a timestamp for individual bytes or lines in a file. There is typically just timestamps associated with the file as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filemtime() as indicated or [stat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) to determine the last modification of a specific file.  With that information you could then determine what is the newest file and extract the contents accordingly.

The only way you can determine what contents of a file are new since last access would be to do a comparison on the previous content to the newest content or have a timestamp that could be used to separate the staleness of the contents.

If there was some way to insert a timestamp to the file then that would allow you to determine what content existed up until that given point.  You would then employ regular expressions to filter the time to only retrieve data after X time.  You would need some way of determining X, which depending on your architecture could be as simple as updating a static file with the last update.  You would then use that value to determine what data is "new".

The second method would be to archive the file after access and then compare the previous contents to the current content in order to determine what content had changed.